# Shorten this reflection property name helper method?

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

I want a static helper method to remove magic strings. Of course, I could pack the property method inside the TestContainer, which would remove the need to provide the TestContainer as argument. This is done nicely [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141370/inotifypropertychanged-property-name-hardcode-vs-reflection).

But I would like to have the helper method in one static class, in case I later decide to optimize my code and remove the method. I managed to get it down to this, but its a little bit ugly (having to provide the string type, looks not very nice).

Any "expression god" knowing a better way. Keep in mind, the static class should be kept universal and not know anything about the TestContainer (otherwise it would be as easy as the link provided)

```
internal class PropertyNameResolving
{
    internal class TestContainer
    {
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    internal static class BindingHelper
    {
        public static string PropertyName<TObject, TValue>(Expression<Func<TObject, TValue>> propertySelector)
        {
            var memberExpression = propertySelector.Body as MemberExpression;
            if (memberExpression != null) return memberExpression.Member.Name;
            else
            throw new Exception("Something went wrong");
        }
    }

    internal static void Test()
    {
        var t = new TestContainer {LastName = "Hans"};
        Console.WriteLine(BindingHelper.PropertyName<TestContainer, string>(x => x.LastName));
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Btw, the output is "LastName" and can be used to set bindings.

And one more question, can I remove the NULL check safely?

Comment: "I want a static helper method to remove magic strings." I don't understand this. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @silky: Support refactoring, especially during development, but still keep all references where I did it in one file (find usages) to remove it later (if performance to bad)

@Itay: Took me a minute to figure out what you meant. This is a test class, don't worry, not my normal style...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 options for you:

- make the class generic, and use inference on the method for the value
- use an example object for inference on the method
- forget about the object type entirely and just use an example

These are all shown below. Re the `null` safety - I would be tempted to check the expression-type (you can also handle methods, btw) - some more code [shown here](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/browse_thread/thread/f44dc57a9dc5168d/02c312dcf8a9a769).

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
internal class TestContainer
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var t = new TestContainer {LastName = "Hans"};            
        string s1 = BindingHelper<TestContainer>
                      .PropertyName(x => x.LastName);            
        string s2 = BindingHelper.PropertyName(t, x => x.LastName);
        string s3 = BindingHelper.PropertyName(() => t.LastName);
    }
}
internal static class BindingHelper
{
    public static string PropertyName<TObject, TValue>(TObject template,
        Expression<Func<TObject, TValue>> propertySelector)
    {
        var memberExpression = propertySelector.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression != null) return memberExpression.Member.Name;
        else
            throw new Exception("Something went wrong");
    }
    public static string PropertyName<TValue>(
         Expression<Func<TValue>> propertySelector)
    {
        var memberExpression = propertySelector.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression != null) return memberExpression.Member.Name;
        else
            throw new Exception("Something went wrong");
    }
}
internal static class BindingHelper<TObject>
{
    public static string PropertyName<TValue>(
        Expression<Func<TObject, TValue>> propertySelector)
    {
        var memberExpression = propertySelector.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression != null) return memberExpression.Member.Name;
        else
            throw new Exception("Something went wrong");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I like method 1 the most... I am sure I will do other things in the BindingHelper later, can't hurt to have the class available anyway. And it looks nice enough..

Answer (score 1):

Because the compiler can imply the type arguments, you shouldn't need to provide  at all in the Test() method without changing anything.

Use BindingHelper.PropertyName(x => x.LastName) and it should work fine as is.

You can't remove the null check safely as your expression could be anything, include method call, which wouldn't count as a MemberExpression.

Comment: I'd say the null check is unnecessary since you throw anyway if it fails.

Comment: No, this does not work.. Try it :-) "cant infere from usage..." error. I will take a look at Marcs solution.