# Getting a C# .NET Resource Property Name By Explicitly Referencing The Property

Tags: .net, reflection

Got a bit of an odd one but there's a reason behind my madness.

I have a resource I have set up with some string properties on it, for example `MenuAdminLabel` and `MenuAccountsLabel` that have values like "Admin" and "Accounts" respectively.  I need to pass the label property names into a method and I'm well aware I could just pass these in as strings like "MenuAdminLabel" and "MenuAccountsLabel" but I would like these to be validated by the compiler rather than being simple strings as there will be a lot of properties on the resource and I want to ensure each reference is correct.

The trouble is if I access `Resource.MenuAdminLabel` I (obviously) get the value of the resource property rather than the property name, I can access the property list by using `typeof(Localisation.Resources).GetProperties()` but, again, I'm having to use a literal string to get the property name from this rather than something explicitly using `Localisation.Resource.MenuAdminLabel` that the compiler can validate.

How can I do this?

Comment: Just for clarification, you don't want to use this expression in an attribute-declaration? You probably need lambda functions for this, which aren't supported when using an attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a problem often faced when implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. The solution is to use a lambda expression like

```
MyMethod(() => Localisation.MenuAdminLabel);
```

instead of

```
MyMethod("MenuAdminLabel");
```

and analyse the expression. One example implementation can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141370/inotifypropertychanged-property-name-hardcode-vs-reflection/143611#143611). For your case, it might look like:

```
private void MyMethod<TValue>(Expression<Func<TValue>> propertySelector)
{
    var memberExpression = propertySelector.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (memberExpression == null)
        throw new ArgumentException();

    string name = memberExpression.Member.Name;

    // Do stuff with name

}
```

Comment: Found a sample here: http://blog.decarufel.net/2009/07/how-to-use-inotifypropertychanged-type_22.html

Comment: I appended return name; and changed the return type to string on that and it works like a dream - thanks a lot.