# Use reflection to assign value of Func<Product, object> property

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, func

If I have a class Product:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public Decimal Price { get; set; } //(Edit) - Added non-string
}
```

And I have a property in another class declared as:

```
Func<Product, object> SortBy { get; set; }
```

I can set SortBy using:

```
SortBy = p => p.Title;
```

But how would I, using reflection, make the same assignment if I had the property name for SortBy stored as a string e.g.

```
string sortField = "Title";

SortBy = /*Some reflection using sortField*/;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) to create a new method at runtime:

```
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Product));
SortBy = Expression.Lambda<Func<Product, object>>(
    Expression.Property(p, sortField),
    p
).Compile();
```

To work with value types, you'll need to insert a cast:

```
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Product));
SortBy = Expression.Lambda<Func<Product, object>>( 
    Expression.TypeAs(Expression.Property(p, sortField), typeof(object)), 
    p
).Compile();
```

Comment: This works perfectly for Strings but won't work for Decimal, Int etc - I am trying to refactor a bunch of code that previously had the sortBy set up using if statements e.g. if(search == "title") sortBy = p => p.Title; if(search == "price") sortBy = p => p.Price;

Comment: It returns a runtime error of: Expression of type 'System.Decimal' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'

Comment: I don't think that a lamdba expression provides automatic boxing and unboxing of value types, you'll need to explicitly box the `Decimal` to an `object` using `Expression.TypeAs`: `Expression.TypeAs(Expression.Property(p, sortField), typeof(object))`.

Comment: @Luke Forder - can you give me the full line of code? i.e. SortBy = ... I'm on day 1 of expression trees so I need some hand holding ;-)

Comment: @DrRob Just replace `Expression.Property(p, sortField)` with the given string.

Comment: I know how it feels :). Building on the above answer:
`var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Product));
SortBy = Expression.Lambda<Func<Product, object>>(
         Expression.TypeAs(Expression.Property(p, sortField), typeof(object)),
         p).Compile();`

Comment: Ladies/Gents we have a winner!! thanks to SLaks and Luke Forder for their help - I'll edit the answer and mark it correct. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

To make it work with decimal and other value types, you can use generics:

```
static void SetSortBy<T>(string sortField) {
    var m = typeof(Product).GetProperty(sortField).GetGetMethod();
    var d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<Product, T>), m) 
            as Func<Product, T>;
    SortBy = product => d(product);
}
```

...

```
SetSortBy<decimal>("Price");
SetSortBy<object>("Title"); // or <string>
```

Comment: this is ok but it requires that I know the Type in order to call SetSortBy which defeats the purpose of the exercise.

Comment: @DrRob: Actually, this approach will work for all reference types using `object`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is effectively the same as this other [SO question/answer on INotifyPropertyChanged by Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1209104/111013).