# How RaisePropertyChanged<T> finds out the property name?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, lambda

There is one overload of this method in `NotificationObject` :-

```
protected void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression);
```

We write in the following way in the setter of property:

```
RaisePropertyChanged(() => PropertyVariable);
```

How does it works ? How it finds the property name out of this Lambda expression ?

Comment: This describes how it could be done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141370/inotifypropertychanged-property-name-hardcode-vs-reflection

Comment: In C# 5, you even don't need reflection magic for it: http://www.robfe.com/2011/09/raising-the-right-propertychanged-with-c-5s-caller-info-attributes/

Comment: I can't help suggesting resharper here, it easily decompiles when you try to go method definitions(F12). You can use other decompilers too for sure like reflector.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An `Expression<TDelegate>` represents the abstract syntax tree of the lambda expression. So you just have to analyze this syntax tree to find out the property name:

```
protected void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
{
    var memberExpr = propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (memberExpr == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("propertyExpression should represent access to a member");
    string memberName = memberExpr.Member.Name;
    RaisePropertyChanged(memberName);
}
```