# NotifyPropertyChanged in .Net 4

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have code like this

```
private decimal m_Amount;
public decimal Amount
{
    get
    {
         return m_Amount;
    }
    set
    {
         m_Amount = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged("Amount");
    }
}
```

But I want to do the without declaring the `m_Amount` variable and Notify also in .Net 4.

In this scenario how do avoid the backup field.

Please suggest me.

Comment: You'll need to use PostSharp to do this.

Comment: Why? Because of the added code you need to write compared to a auto-implemented property? Then just write a custom Code Snippet for your shown code.

Comment: Adding extra variable is causing problem in my application. So i need to avoid that.

Comment: Why should be a variable a problem?

Comment: @BrittoRaj: "is causing problem" gives almost no information. That's like going to a doctor and saying "There's something wrong with me, what are you going to prescribe?" without describing any symptoms.

Comment: My application has legacy code and each class has 250 Properties and it almost 10 classes like this. So i am getting Memory leak problem

Comment: @JonSkeet Indeed! I'm also interested to find out what's the reason for this.

Comment: You are getting a memoryleak problem by using backing fields?? Never heard of that.

Comment: @BrittoRaj What makes you think that adding a property would cause a memory leak? That's insane!

Comment: @BrittoRaj while we are on the subject. Since when did .net 4 and WPF   become "legacy"?

Comment: @Alex: "My application has legacy code" != ".NET 4 is legacy"

Comment: It just sounded funny in my head, that's all :)

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you use a C# 5 compiler (VS2012/VS2013) and the [`Microsoft.Bcl`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl/) NuGet package, you can use `CallerMemberNameAttribute` with .NET 4. You'll still need to declare the field separately though, because you can't just use an automatically-implemented property. (You're doing more than just a simple read/write.)

Alternatively, you *could* use an AOP package like PostSharp - I wouldn't start using PostSharp *just* to get away from writing properties like this, but if you have other cross-cutting concerns you want to handle declaratively, it would be useful.

If you don't want to use the BCL NuGet package, you *can* just declare [`CallerMemberNameAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) yourself - just copy and paste the declaration into your own code, but making sure you put it into the right namespace (`System.Runtime.CompilerServices`). Note that this will cause issues when you later update to .NET 4.5.

Comment: @BrittoRaj: So no external libraries *at all*, not even a Microsoft NuGet package? In that case, no, you can't do better than you've got. (You could implement `CallerMemberNameAttribute` yourself, but that would be a pain when you later updated to .NET 4.5...)

Comment: But declare extra variable is causing the problem.

Comment: @BrittoRaj: *What* problem? You've given us no information at all as to why you're trying to avoid the code you've already got.

Comment: My application has legacy code and each class has 250 Properties and it almost 10 classes like this. So i am getting Memory leak problem.

Comment: An autoimplemented Property has also a backing field. You just don't see it.

Comment: @BrittoRaj: Introducing a `decimal` variable won't create a memory *leak*... and an automatically implemented property still takes memory...

Comment: Jon this is i gave sample. But all the variables are String.

Comment: @BrittoRaj Same difference

Comment: @BrittoRaj: So why is that relevant? If your problem is basically "My application needs to store more data than I have memory" then there's not a lot that can be done to fix that (without complicating things by paging out to disk etc).

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243327/how-raisepropertychangedt-finds-out-the-property-name) should help you. You use it this way

```
RaisePropertyChanged(() => Amount);
```

Comment: But that still need backup field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AOP ([Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)) to achieve this.
You can either do AOP by IL Weaving or Interceptors. For this particular problem i would got with IL Weaving.

These are two popular for IL weaving:

**Fody**

[Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) is free & open source and available as nuget package.
There is the [PropertyChanged Extension](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) which will implement the property changed notification aspect for you. It is also available as nuget package.

We have been using fody for quite a while now and are extremely happy with it. Your code could be as simple as this:

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class SomeViewModel
{
    Decimal Amount{ get; set; }
}
```

**PostSharp**

[PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) Is commercial.
[This](http://www.postsharp.net/aspects/examples/inotifypropertychanged) explains how to weave property change notification.

---

**Interceptor**

You could also implement the property changed notification aspect using an [interceptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interceptor_pattern). One of the popular interceptor frameworks is [Castle.DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/), another one would be [LinFu Dynamic proxy](https://github.com/philiplaureano/LinFu.DynamicProxy).
However, i would not recommend to use an interceptor since it results in a less-nice design. I'm not going into details unless someone will request it ;-)

Comment: Without any tools how do achieve in .Net4

Comment: You can't. It's not possible.

Comment: Also consider that both tools integrate into the build process and don't need any manual labor for every build or something like that. With Fody, all you got to do is add the nuget package and you're set.