# How to write MVVM properties?

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm

With MVVM I always see these both methods for properties:

```
    private int myProperty;
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return myProperty; }
        set
        {
            myProperty = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
        }
    }
```

and

```
    private int myProperty;
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return myProperty; }
        set
        {
            myProperty = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.MyProperty);
        }
    }
```

The first one use an hardcoded string to NotifyPropertyChanged and the second one use a lambda expression to NotifyPropertyChanged. I don't want to create a debate to ask what is the better solution but I would like to understand what are the differences bewteeen these two solution. What are the consequences of using one or the other?

Correct me if I'm wrong but the lambda expression solution should use more memory and should be slower than the hardcoded string because the NotifyPropertyChanged method of the base class use delegate and reflection. But the hardcoded string solution may create stupid bug because it's a string and nothing to tell me I correctly wrote it.

Comment: Yes you are right: the lamda version is slower but safer while the string version is fast but unsafe. What is your question?

Comment: This has already been asked? http://stackoverflow.com/q/141370/81053 Or at least worth reading the top answer

Comment: @nemesv That is my question. I'm interested to know what are the other differencies between these two solutions. Just to really well understand the code. How much is the second method slower?

Comment: You will never, EVER, find yourself excising lambdas from your application in order to reduce its memory footprint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second expression would either generate a compiler error on the property name change, or would automatically change with it (via the Rename support in VS or ReSharper).

So basically, you gain compiler support for property names. The wrong name provided to the notify would mean that data-binding would break. With string names, this breakage would be silent.

In a small UI the choice is irrelevant in my opinion, but in a large application with a heavy UI layer the extra support against bugs can pay itself off in the long run.

Performance won't be *problematically* slower, don't forget, binding is reflection-powered anyway. Performance, as always, is relative. The hard-coded version will technically be faster because it doesn't need to reflect the property name out of the meta-data. How much faster, I'm not sure.

Comment: Of course, one should not forget that there is the other side to property binding - XAML, and so the second option does not ensure *total* compile time safety.

Comment: @user676571 No, but with the XAML you are expecting it, a property notify might be less obvious to spot.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than repeating that code of NotifyPropertyChanged for every property, I felt the below code is more cleaner

Create a Set method in your ViewModel Base

```
protected bool Set<T>(Expression<Func<T>> selectorExpression, ref T field, T value)
{
    if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
       return false;
    field = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged(selectorExpression);
    return true;
}
```

and use them as

```
string title;
public string Title
{
   get { return title; }
   set { Set(() => Title, ref title, value); }
}
```

Comment: What is the return value used for?

Comment: Use it, If you want to know whether the operation has changed the underlying private variable

Comment: Wow, its almost as if you're re-implementing the DependencyObject framework upon which WPF is built.  Wait, you are.

Comment: @Will I didn't get you. I am fairly new to WPF, so it would be great if you could give me more details on that.

Comment: @MobleJoseph: WPF is built upon [DependencyObjects and DependencyProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx), the purpose of which is to support binding, attached properties, etc etc etc.  There comes a time (after INPC, IMHO) when you gain no benefit from attempting to reproduce the logic of the DepObj framework.  At this point, its better to extend your ViewModels from DependencyObject and be done.

Comment: @Will Most of the articles around shows the example of implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface over POCO. Can you refer any article which shows us how to use the Dependency Objects to create my viewmodels ?

Comment: @MobleJoseph: The link above is a good place to start, and [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx) covers DPs well.  Its as simple as extending DependencyObject and following the DependencyProperty pattern when adding properties.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following method in a base class implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and it is so easy and convenient:

```
public void NotifyPropertyChanged()
    {
        StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();

        MethodBase method = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod();

        if (!(method.Name.StartsWith("get_") || method.Name.StartsWith("set_")))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The NotifyPropertyChanged() method can only be used from inside a property");
        }

        string propertyName = method.Name.Substring(4);

        RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
```