# Updating UI based on property change in a view model

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm new to WPF, so there's probably something basic I'm missing here. I have an application that looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Test Application" Height="647" Width="723" Background="#88B0FF">

    <DockPanel Name="MainDock">
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="5,0,5,0" x:Name="PingButton" Click="PingButton_OnClick">Ping</Button>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Output}" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

The code-behind is like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Model _applicationModel = new Model();
    public Model ApplicationModel {
        get { return _applicationModel; }
        set { _applicationModel = value; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = ApplicationModel;
        ApplicationModel.Output = "Not clicked";
    }

    private void PingButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ApplicationModel.Output = "Clicked";
    }
}
```

I have a small class called Model that implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public string Output { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I run this application, and the text box displays the text "Not clicked". When I click the button, I would expect that the text would change. It does not. The "ApplicationModel" object is updated, and this is reflected in the DataContext; I have a breakpoint in the OnPropertyChanged() method, however, and it appears that it's never being called.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OnPropertyChanged()` isn't being called because *you're not calling it.*
There is no special magic that wires up calls to `OnPropertyChanged` by itself, so you need to do it yourself.

Specifically, you should modify your `Output` property to call it when it changes (and it wouldn't hurt to do the same for your `ApplicationModel` property:

```
private string output;
public string Output
{
    get { return output; }
    set
    {
        if (output != value)
        {
            output = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Output");
        }
    }
}
```

If you're targeting .NET 4.5 you can utilize the [`CallerMemberName` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx) to reduce boilerplate code; [This article](http://danrigby.com/2012/03/01/inotifypropertychanged-the-net-4-5-way/) explains how to do so. Then you'll have something like this:

```
private string output;
public string Output
{
    get { return output; }
    set { SetProperty(ref output, value); }
}
```

If you're using .NET 4.0 or below, you can use expression trees, as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/143611/389966).

Comment: Bah, I was hoping for some reflection magic here. Any best practices for reducing the boilerplate here?

Comment: Not a fan of [CallerMemberName] because it won't work if you need to notify a different property than what's being called. Code will end up being a mix between both ways.