# Is there a way that I can simplify the definitions of properties in my ViewModels?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a very large number of properties that look like this:

```
string _aBtnState;
public string ABtnState { get => _aBtnState; set => SetProperty(ref _aBtnState, value); }
```

Here's the SetProperty method I use:

```
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    protected virtual bool SetProperty<T>(
        ref T backingStore, T value,
        [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "",
        Action onChanged = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
            return false;

        backingStore = value;
        onChanged?.Invoke();
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "") =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

}
```

Is there any way that this could be simplified to anything like this:

```
public object ABtnState { get; set; }
```

or maybe

```
SetMyProperty(ABtnState);
```

and still be made to have the same functionality.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141370/inotifypropertychanged-property-name-hardcode-vs-reflection

Comment: There is this: https://github.com/shiftkey/NotifyPropertyWeaver which kinda cheats, and injects the notify code at compile time. May or may not work for you.

Comment: Fody will automatically include INPC for you

Comment: @Jason - Can you explain what Fody is and how it can be used?

Comment: https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there's a simpler way to do it. I recommend you to create a snippet in Visual Studio for speeding up the process.

```
private $type$ $field$;

public $type$ $property$
{
    get => this.$field$;
    set => this.SetValue(ref this.$field$, value);
}
```

VSCode

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

VS Mac

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/snippets?view=vsmac-2019

VS Windows

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2019